# Ionic3 video integration is not working on web

Tags: ionic-framework, web, video, ionic3, videocall

I want to integrate one to one video call feature to the Ionic3 project, it should support all platforms like WEB, Android, IOS. I tried so many APIs like **VONAGE**, **PUBNUB-WebRtc**, **ZohoDesk**, **OpenTok**, **Enablex**. But all libraries are supporting only mobile platforms through Ionic, those are not supporting on the web. Can anyone help to do this?
thankyou

Comment: Dod you try openVido?

Comment: no, is it support Ionic framework? is there examples for the ionic, please share here. thankyou @MostafaHarb

Comment: Yes it is , they in there docs examples about it.